# synonyms/phrases/poems related to: 情深恭敬少

Tags: synonyms, phrase, equivalent-phrase, poetry, proverb

*ABC Proverbs*

> 情深恭敬少 ,知己谈笑多
>
> Lit [When] friendship [is] deep, formalities are few; [for] close confidants, chats [and] laughter are many.
>
> Fig Intimate friends don't stand on ceremony.

What synonyms/phrases/poems are related to 情深恭敬少?

Online material mostly just explains the phrase itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The so call " poem" itself is not very polished. I suppose the person who wrote "情深恭敬少 " was thinking an idea along the line of " 熟不拘禮 " ( being so close, there's no need for formalities" )

For 知己談笑多 which is not a convincing statement because 酒肉朋友 談笑 more. Anyway, a phrase "酒逢知己千杯少" (It is such a joy to drink with good friends, one can forget how much he has drunken.) is from a famous poem that depict heartfelt interaction between good friends.

Comment: I was also asking for any related poems/materials that talk about this subject & 熟不拘禮 like you mentioned.

Comment: First of all, 恭敬少 imply "disrespect" it is totally against the Chinese nature. For Chinese, we treat the people we love the most with utmost respect. 不拘禮 ( not follow formalities strictly) is not 不敬 ( disrespect) but sign of closeness and fondness.